# How to have multi-layered kind of shadow/gradient in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, gradient, shadow

[image]

I am trying to achieve this layout. The upper part is a bit dark and it decreases as we move down making it complete transparent. I tried a couple of gradient variations but didn't get the desired results. Does anybody have idea of how to achieve this. Is it gradient or shadow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a gradient file and use this code you can increase or decrease transparency as you want

layout-->new file-->layout resource file--> give any name

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient android:startColor="#B71A1A1A"
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#00FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    </selector>
```